# XAMPP PDO Sqlite directory

Tags: php, sqlite, pdo

The sqlite PHP PDO code below works when i run it through PHP command line from the htdocs directory in XAMPP.  However, when I run it as localhost, it cannot find S2.db.  There are the correct permissions on that directory...

What is the right way to access a different directory with ATTACH DATABASE when run through XAMPP?  Thank you!

```
$db = new PDO('sqlite:S1.db');
$db->exec("ATTACH DATABASE '../S2.db' as table1");
```

Comment: Try using an absolute path instead of a relative.

Comment: Yes I just tried that 1 minute before you posted it!  Thank you!

Comment: so.... did it work?

Comment: Sorry yes it did.  Thank you!